# How to save photos from RestFB graph API call on Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am using RestFB to get photos from an album:

```
    com.restfb.Connection<Post> postFeed = facebookClient.fetchConnection("445465465756756765" + "/photos", Post.class);

    for (List<Post> postPage : postFeed) {
        for (Post aPost : postPage) {
            System.out.println("fb.com/" + aPost.getId());
        }
    }
```

And I see [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API) explorer output as:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "created_time": "2017-05-19T21:52:31+0000",
      "name": "Honored to welcome Prime Minister Justin Trudeau to Seattle this week.",
      "id": "10154558167016961"
    },
```

And I get output in console as `fb.com/10154558167016961`.

And when I type above in browser I can see a picture. But how do I download or save this picture?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use the `Photo` type instead of `Post` and you need to add `Parameter.with("fields","images")` to the `fetchConnection` call.

On iterating over the connection you can access on every photo the images with `getImages()`. In the returned list of `Images` every object has a `source` field. Using the java equivalent to wget you can then fetch the binary content of the image.